# Append does not write to new line on a csv file

Tags: vba

I have an Outlook macro that runs when an email arrives and everything is working fine.

When an email arrives I use the below code to add the subject and some text to the CSV file :

```
strFile_Path = "C:\Users\XX\Desktop\test.csv"
Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
Print #1, sbjt & ";0"
Close #1
```

However when  I add some text manually to the csv file, when the Macro runs it adds next to the line not to a new line, how can I solve this? (Write also doesn't work instead of Print and it adds Double quotations)

Comment: `Print` only appends a new line at the end of the line you write. You eiter need to make sure you always have a new line when editing the file with a text editor or you use VBA to check before you use `print`.

Comment: Hi @Storax, how can I use VBA to check before I use print if there is a text ?

Comment: If the text file is not too big you could read the text file into a string, check the last char and append your string with a new line or without. Another slower way would be to read the text file line by line and do your checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your file is not really big (Megabytes) and you are working on Windows (because on Mac you will have different line endings):

First read the file into memory, check if the last two characters are Carriage Return+Line Feed. If not, first use `print` with an empty line - that will add the line break. Now you can print your text.

```
Dim needNewLine As Boolean
needNewLine = FileNeedsLineBreak(strFile_Path)
Dim f As Integer
f = FreeFile
Open filename For Append As f
If needNewLine Then Print #f, ""
Print #f, sbjt & ";0"
... Now add all your lines you want to write...
Close f
```

I have split the tasks, checking if a Linebreak is missing is done using a function. Note that you need to call this function *before* you open it for append because it needs to open it also.

```
Function FileNeedsLineBreak(filename as String) as boolean
    Dim f As Long
    f = FreeFile
    Open filename For Input As f
    Dim buffer As String
    buffer = Input(LOF(f), f)

    If Len(buffer) >= 2 Then 
        FileNeedsLineBreak = (Right(buffer, 2) <> vbCrLf)
    End If
    Close f
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried this and it works

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an Ansi encoded text file then the following function will read the complete file into a string

```
Function ReadFile(fileName As String) As String
    
    Dim iFile As Integer
    Dim fileText As String

    iFile = FreeFile
    Open fileName For Input As FreeFile
    fileText = VBA.Input(VBA.LOF(iFile), iFile)
    Close iFile
    
    ReadFile = fileText
    
End Function
```

In the next part of the code I use the [Filesystemobject](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) to write the string back to the file after having checked how to add my string "Test".

```
Sub changeFile()
    
    Const fileName = "D:\TEMP\TEST.CSV"

    Dim fileTxt As String
    fileTxt = ReadFile(fileName)  ' read the file into a string

    ' Check if there is a new line at the end
    If Right(fileTxt, 1) = vbCrLf Or Right(fileTxt, 1) = vbLf Then
        fileTxt = fileTxt & "Test"
    Else
        fileTxt = fileTxt & vbCrLf & "Test"
    End If

    ' wrtie the file using FSO
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim Fileout As Object
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName, True, False)
    Fileout.Write fileTxt
    Fileout.Close
End Sub
```